# "Instant Reverse" Exception for .NET Executable or .DLL and ? about Assembly Manifests

Tags: .net, visual-paradigm

I'm using a product called [Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/) to generate UML from any relevant data I can amass.

I've been happy with the reversal for the UML of solutions and projects, however, I want to take it farther and visually analyze some common .NET libraries or any executable that might be composed of the typical .NET libraries. As far as I can tell, the tool is *possibly* not capable of dealing with .NET Core but I have tried to perform the same steps on older libraries that would only be in the .NET Framework era of tech.

Unfortunately, - I can't embed images - so I'll provide a [link to the image of the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWHYm.png) that I am getting during the generative process. The stack trace is the same for every .NET dll or executable that I try to instantly inspect and the program complains that it is missing the assembly manifest.

I understand not having a manifest for any given (dll) library, however, it was my understanding that when looking at an executable it would contain a manifest that will come from the compilation process?

If anyone can help me solve the problems of either the software exception or the exception in my own brain for this type of problem then that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant! I agree I don't think the question is particularly useful in this example it is just meant to be a contrived context where I went looking for the first executable I could find on my machine - I will find a use case - but I did just want to know why the program was spitting this out for every binary...this is probably why.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by some of its dependent libraries are not included in the reverse engineering scope (the engine will not load system libraries for reverse engineering). Therefore please make sure you have included all related libraries in the reverse engineering path so that the engine can pickup and resolve the dependency and perform reverse engineering to your binaries.

Comment: Thanks again Rain! :)